# How to enable payment method in woocommerce only for certain simple and variable products by id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to enable a payment method in woocomerce only for certain simple and variable products by id or in some other way? On the Internet, I found a way to enable it for certain categories, but I also need it for specific products

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_by_category', 25 );

function payment_gateway_by_category( $available_gateways ) {

  
  if ( is_admin() ) {
    return $available_gateways;
  }

  $gateway_slug = 'wc_tinkoff_kvk'; 
  $is_available = true; 
  $cat_ids = array( 45, 47 ); 

  
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $value ) {
    
    if( $product_cats = get_the_terms( $value[ 'product_id' ], 'product_cat' ) ) {
      foreach ( $product_cats as $product_cat ) {
        if ( in_array( $product_cat->term_id, $cat_ids ) ) {
          $is_available = false; 
          break 2;
        }
      }
    }
  }

 
  if ( false === $is_available ){
    unset( $available_gateways[ $gateway_slug ] );
  }

  return $available_gateways; 

}
```